# Blank screen after loggin in from sleep mode

Tags: xubuntu, password, suspend

If I close the lid to let it sleep, open it and type in my password, right after that I get a blank screen. How can I fix this. Running xubuntu 15.04.

Comment: Forget it. I've tried every solution from the internet under the sun and nothing has fixed the problem.

Comment: Same exact thing happens to me with Xubuntu 15.04 on an ASUS Zenbook UX305FA-ASM1. (Intel video)